# How to create a timestamp server for signature purposes

Tags: timestamp, certificate, digital-signature

I would like to have my own timestamp server, so I can used it in the signature process of a binary file.

I found the link: http://owcapage.wordpress.com/linux-time-stamp-server/

However I cannot get working. Maybe because I can't reach: www.opentsa.org

Is there any alternatives? On linux, windows, doesn't matter...

Comment: Doing this has little sense cause your signatures won't be trusted anywhere (unless you plan to deploy complete PKI infrastructure yourself).

Comment: At least your time stamps won't be trusted far beyond your own organisation, while the signatures may be accepted during their certificate validity. Or are those signatures only intended for use inside your organisation, e.g. for work flow signing?

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp sounds coherent, however, see my reply to mkl.

Comment: @mkl, this will be used inside our organization to overcome an issue we're facing in our own algorithm to check cert validity. Having control over the timestamp, we think we could sign with an old timestamp (within the valid range of our old certificate) an overcome this issue. Is that even possible?

Comment: Probably. Signature time stamps are applied after signature creation. As long as the time of the time stamp is not before a probably present signing tine attribute in there signature... This procedure obviously heals the process technically only...

Comment: @mkl thanks! With that in main, do you some tips on how to create this server, since as stated on my question, I can't get working...

Comment: To me it looks like you actually do need the patch from opentsa. And no, i can't reach them either... Neither do i have experiences with other free tsa software. (actually the company i work at offer tsa software as product, but that's a commercial product...)

Comment: @mkl thanks for your time. As soon as I find a solution‚ I'll share. It

Comment: @SantiagoAgüero sorry for the bump here but meanwhile you found any solution? thanks

Comment: @Xplouder it has been such a long time since I faced with this. The only thing that I remember of is that I could finally change the time of a certificate, but it stays as invalid.

Comment: Alright, thank you anyway :)))

Answer (score 5):

You can create timestamp authority server using **openssl ts**
https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/ts.html